# the meaning of なりに in わからないなりに

Tags: grammar

I saw a usage that defied my understanding of なり:

> ことねは彼が話すサッカーの話をわからない**なりに**相槌を打ちながら聞いていた。

As far as the definitions given here: [なり](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/165329/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A/), I don't think any of them are a perfect fit. Is there another meaning to なりに when used in a context like this? I would guess "although", but if it's that, what's the nuance?

Comment: http://www.tanos.co.uk/jlpt/jlpt1/grammar/usage/ and CTRL-F なり might be what you are looking for.

Comment: The なり is not a particle. It's a noun. See [definition #4-イ on goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/165321/m0u/). 「名詞または形容詞の連体形に付いて、そのものにふさわしい、また、それに応じて、という意を表す。「弟―の考え」「狭ければ狭い―に住むしかない」」

Comment: More context: http://fxconsulting.jp/gyanburu/nitijo/ferumi.html わからないなりに shows up twice on this page. I have a rough idea of what it might mean but nothing for sure.

Comment: http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AB

Answer (score 3):

You are looking up the wrong word -- the particle 「なり」.  The 「なり」 in question is a ***noun***.

These need to be treated as two completely different words.

> 『Phrase A + なり + に + Phrase B』
>
> = "Performing B ***in the restricted or predetermined conditions*** of A"

***Grammar Point:***

Phrase A must end in a noun or the [連体形]{れんたいけい} (attributive form) of a word that inflects.  No exceptions.

「わからない」 is in the 連体形, so it works.

Restricted conditions: **Kotone does not really understand the soccer stuff that he talks about**.

Despite that, **she was listening to him (attentively), chiming in every now and then**.